# Get Instance Images name with the gcloud python api

Tags: python, google-compute-engine

How can I retrieve the image name of an instance thanks to the gcloud compute engine API in python?

when I list my instances with

```
compute.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone , filter ='status eq '+ instance_status).execute()
```

The response doesn't give me the instance image name (debian-9).

Comment: I am not aware of this information being stored anywhere after an instance has been launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the source image using the Python API use the below request:

```
request = service.disks().get(project=project, zone=zone, disk=disk)
response = request.execute()
```

The output body has `'sourceImage'` field for more information see the public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/get) as well see belwoe an example:

```
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Project ID for this request.
project = 'my-project'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# The name of the zone for this request.
zone = 'my-zone'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

# Name of the persistent disk to return.
disk = 'my-disk'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

request = service.disks().get(project=project, zone=zone, disk=disk)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```